# how to add 1 to a value each time a new item is inserted SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

well I am stuck with a simple but very irritating problem.

I am creating a program that will save documents to *SharePoint*, when I click it will save the documents:

```
name,
date,
username,
location 
version
```

to SQL. Now here is my problem. Each new documents version needs to increment/add by 1.
So lets say we have version - 1 it must be version -2 when clicked 
and I can't use auto-increment because there might be different docs 
with different names and the version needs to be added according to the correct doc name.

Now be-warned I am tired as hell and my SQL proc is not pretty:

```
 @username varchar(100),
 @Type varchar(100),
 @Name varchar(100),
 @Version int,
 @Location varchar(100)
 AS
 SET @VERSION = 1
 INSERT INTO TABLE (Username,[Date],[Type],Name,[Version],Location)
 VALUES('Wolf',GetDate(),'pdf','doc',@version ,@Location)
 SELECT max([Version]) FROM table
```

this is roughly what it will look like now I just need to be able to add 1 to the version each time a new doc is inserted with the name lets say for argument sake its a Manual.

aah to the oaks editing this please note i have not slept in 48 hours i am tired and spelling is the least of my worries

Comment: select max([Version])+1 from table?

Comment: if it is that simple i am going to hang myself that or get some sleep i will check it out and get back to you thanks Yos

Comment: no such luck it repeatedly throws 1 each time a click so it is 1,1,1,1 and so on it does not add

Comment: you know Dr that sounds like it could work i will try it and get back to you p.s my proficiency with sql leaves a lot to be desired

Comment: i would not insert the version value manually, but rather default it to 1; then if a new insert happens let a trigger take care of things: look if a document with the same (name, or what ever identifies it uniquely) exists and add the highest found version for that row to the version of the just inserted row (sorry i deleted my original comment you were responding to as i saw in the comments below it was not exactly what you wanted, though close :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     @username varchar(100),
     @Type varchar(100),
     @Name varchar(100),
     @Version int,
     @Location varchar(100)



      as 

      IF NOT EXISTS(select * from table where type = 'USERGUIDE') 
      BEGIN
  SET @VERSION = 1
      END ELSE BEGIN
  SET @VERSION = (SELECT MAX(VERSION) + 1 FROM table WHERE TYPE = 'USERGUIDE')
      END

      SELECT @VERSION [VERSION]
```

Comment: thanks  shahid,Yossarian,drCopyPaste and obsidian i managed to figure something out the code above does the trick

Comment: Shahid your code helped alot thank you very much it gave me the idea for the above code

Comment: It bears pointing out that your code is inefficient. You are querying the table for the record, then querying it again to get the version number. With a bit of tweaking, you can make it more efficient by pulling the version number and using it in your `If` statement.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you are always setting the Version Number to 1 before the insert:

```
SET @VERSION = 1
```

You need to get the current max version from your table *prior* to the insert. Try this:

```
Declare @username varchar(100) = 'Wolf',
@Type varchar(100) = 'pdf',
@Name varchar(100) = 'doc',
@Version int,
@Location varchar(100) = 'TestLoc'

Select @Version = IsNull(Max([Version]), 0) + 1
From Test
Where Name = @Name

 INSERT INTO Test (Username,[Date],[Type],Name,[Version],Location)
 VALUES(@username,GetDate(),@type,@name,@version ,@Location)

 Select Max([Version]) From Test
 Where Name = @Name
```

You can see this in action on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/592e9/4)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using triggers.

As I pointed out in the comments I would not recommend inserting the `version` explicitly, but rather let the column default to the value 1 and if new rows are inserted that have name and type of already existing rows, a trigger searches for the highest versions for this items and updates the inserted rows.

Note that this is `T-SQL` (SQL-Server, since you did not specify your DBMS ;))
Though I am pretty sure only the `OUTER APPLY`-keyword and `TOP` are T-SQL-specific.

I did not quite manage to upload this to sqlfiddle, so I include table definition and sample inserts here so you can easily reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), name NVARCHAR(127), type NVARCHAR(10), date DATETIME, username NVARCHAR(127), location NVARCHAR(127), version INT DEFAULT 1);

GO

CREATE TRIGGER VersionUpdater
ON Documents
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

UPDATE Documents
    SET Documents.version = Documents.Version + ISNULL(LastVersion.version, 0)
  FROM Documents
  INNER JOIN inserted ON Documents.ID = inserted.ID
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1
            version
        FROM Documents AS ExistingDocuments
        WHERE
            ExistingDocuments.name = inserted.name
            AND ExistingDocuments.type = inserted.type
            AND ExistingDocuments.ID != inserted.ID
        ORDER BY version DESC
  ) AS LastVersion
GO

INSERT INTO Documents (name, type, date, username, location)
    SELECT 'master yodas wisdoms', 'pdf', GETUTCDATE(), 'luke skywalker', 'Tatooine'

INSERT INTO Documents (name, type, date, username, location)
    SELECT 'master yodas wisdoms', 'pdf', GETUTCDATE(), 'luke skywalker', 'Tatooine'

INSERT INTO Documents (name, type, date, username, location)
    SELECT 'master yodas wisdoms', 'pdf', GETUTCDATE(), 'luke skywalker', 'Tatooine'
```

If you then `SELECT * FROM Documents` you will see three entries that all have a different version.

PS: To those that are wondering: UNIONING the three inserts won't get the desired result, but that should also not be a viable usecase in that you insert 3 versions of the same document at one time.

PPS: I know yoda does not originate from Tatooine, it's just sample data, but feel free to correct me ;)

Comment: thanks alot i will remember this in the future DR it will come in handy

Answer (score 3):

I really do not know vb.net AT ALL, but I will allow myself to summarize what is being asked here and attempt to answer in PLAIN SQL (I'm on oracle, firebird and mysql):

- you have a table called `TABLE` with docs and one of the columns is `VERSION`
- whenever you upload a new version of a doc *WITH THE SAME NAME*, a new version of this record should be *INSERTED* with it's `VERSION` incremented
- you want to end up having multiple records for each `NAME`, differing only by `VERSION` and insert date.

If this is all true, this is how it should be done:

- before insert, find out if you have that `NAME` already
- if exists - read `VERSION` from that record, use 0 (zero) if it doesn't
- increment `VERSION` and insert as normal,

This leads to the following query, this works in ORACLE, might be a bit confusing, because the query is somewhat backwards compared the above order:

```
insert into TABLE (Username, Date, Type, Name, Version, Location)
  VALUES('Wolf', CURRENT_DATE, 'pdf', 'doc',
  (select nvl(max(Version)+1, 1) from TABLE where Name = 'pdf'),
  'Location');
```

Notice the `SELECT` in third line - you should bind the same variable to the Name in this subquery as you would in second line in `INSERT` statement. Having said that, subquery

```
select nvl(<something>+1 , 1) from TABLE;
```

will get you `<something>` *incremented by 1*, **OR** a number `1`, in case `<something>` evaluated to `NULL`, which it will, if a given `Name` does not yet exist in `TABLE`. In this case, our `<something>` will be `MAX(VERSION)` from the same table incremented by 1 (btw, you need an index on `Name`). Note that `NULL+1` is still `NULL`, hence we need to use NVL.

This was moderately simple, beautiful way to do this *on Oracle*.

**On MySQL**, there is no way you can select anything from the same table you are about to insert into with one statement (AFAIK), so this will be a two-step process. First, we will select `MAX(VERSION)+1` or digit `1`, then we will insert as normal. We could use a procedure to wrap this up, or just two statements, like so (again, pure SQL, I tested it):

```
select COALESCE(MAX(VERSION)+1, 1) from TABLE where Name = 'pdf' into @incver;
```

and immediately

```
insert into TABLE (Username, Date, Type, Name, Version, Location)
  VALUES ('Wolf', now(), 'pdf', 'doc',  @incver, 'Location');
```

Note that the first query will behave somewhat like an INSERT query, meaning it will silently put a value into variable `@incver` and say that it affected 1 row. No result will be displayed. Variable `@incver` is then used in the second statement. Also, `COALESCE` on MySQL does roughly the same thing that `NVL` does on ORACLE, and `CURRENT_DATE` becomes a function called `now()`.

Finally, **Firebird**.... which is the same as on ORACLE! Except CURRENT_DATE will now be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or some concatenation of CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIME.

I hope you will infer some useful things from all this, that could be integrated in your vb.net

Answer (score 2):

Try it...

```
 @username varchar(100),
 @Type varchar(100),
 @Name varchar(100),
 @Version int,
 @Location varchar(100)

 as 
 IF EXISTS(SELECT Version FROM table WHERE Type=@Type AND Name = @Name)
 BEGIN
    SET @Version = (SELECT    TOP(1) Version FROM table 
                    WHERE     Type=@Type 
                    AND       Name = @Name 
                    ORDER BY  Version DESC);
    SET @Version = @Version+1;
 END
 ELSE
    SET @VERSION = 1;

 Insert into table .......
```

Comment: sorry shadi i tried this it does not work but thank you for the effort

Comment: @Wolf please add `Table schema` and your `expected` result(data) to question.

Comment: shad all it has to do is just add 1 to the version table each time a new doc is inserted thats all the rest of it i can do without problems the version starts at 1 and if a doc is added it should be version 2 this is a log so i dont want to update anything the new doc is in a new row

Comment: @Wolf version must be change to 2 if your are added same record next time or on each new entry you want to increment version.??

Comment: e.g `Type=pdf` and `Name=doc`, and new record is add having same type and name then version will be 2. My query will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

your code should work as you are using it in a different enviroment.

```
 @username varchar(100),
 @Type varchar(100),
 @Name varchar(100),
 @Version int,
 @Location varchar(100)
 AS
 SET @VERSION = 1
 INSERT INTO TABLE (Username,[Date],[Type],Name,[Version],Location)
 VALUES('Wolf',GetDate(),'pdf','doc',@version ,@Location)
 SELECT max([Version]) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

make it pretty easy. just create an Scaller Function and set it as a default value. for example

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getMaxValue() 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return int;

    SELECT @return = (max(Version) +1) From Table_1

    if (@return  is null)
        set @return =1;

    RETURN @return;

END
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search by type and name , because document with name and types is a condition on which you want to increment the version.

@username varchar(100),
 @Type varchar(100),
 @Name varchar(100),
 @Version int,
 @Location varchar(100)

Select @Version = IsNull(Max([Version]), 0) + 1
 From table
 Where [Type] = @Type && Name = @Name

INSERT INTO table (Username,[Date],[Type],Name,[Version],Location)
 VALUES(@username,GetDate(),@Type,@Name,@Version,@Location)